# POST in Javascript and redirect for file download

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, redirect

I've read many articles in this site or other sites ([Redirect with POST to application/csv without form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691656/redirect-with-post-to-application-csv-without-form), [jQuery.post(), PHP and redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160840/jquery-post-php-and-redirects), ... ) but without any valuable solutions. 
My problem is the following :

1. in my site (html5, JQuery), there is a table. A feature of the site
   is to export the table as a csv file which will be available for
   download,
2. This feature is implemented as follow :

   2.1 a javascript is called which extracts the data of the table,

   2.2 this JS redirect to a php service and pass as arguments the datas. The code is the
   following :

`var url= jmcnet.request.getOrigin()+'/commons/php/dt_csv_export.php' ;
location.href = url+"?action=generate&csv_type=export_task&csv_data=" +encodeURIComponent(csv);`

2.3 The php script format the input (csv_data parameter), write a temporay file and returns the content of the temporary file. The code is the following :

```
$h = @fopen($csv_file_name, 'w');
      fputcsv($h, $csv_row, ',', '"');
      fclose($h);
      // export file content to JS
      header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
   header('Content-Type: text/ csv; charset =UTF-8');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export-table.csv');
   header(' Pragma: no-cache');
   echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
   readfile($csv_file_name);
```

2.4 The php file delete (unlink) the temporary file and exit,

My problem is that when the table is long, the URL called is not valid and the JS call to Php is down.

So, I imagine the 3 following solutions but no one is evident and all leads to other problems :

1. S1  : dont do a GET but a POST in JS. So the size of the csv_data
   doesn't matter anymore. The problem is that I will have the content
   of the csv file in JS var after the call succeed and I don't know or
   find how to redirect to a page which content is in a JS var ? I
   guess I will lose all header information doing this.
2. S2 : compress in JS the csv_data parameter and decompress it in Php.
   I just don't know how to do that and if it possible ....
3. S3 : call the php with a POST. Modify the Php to return the URL of
   the temporary file, and do a redirect in JS to this temporay URL.
   The problems are that my Php must generate a file into a dir
   directly visible on the Internet, the file name must be unique and
   there is no way to simply delete the file after it has been read by
   browser (and I hate cron or what else).

I'm sure I'm not the first one to have this problem, so I need your help to see what is the best practice for this problem.

Comment: So the data that is in the table is not available in the backend via a database or something else? What about persisting it, while exporting, to fetch it on the redirected page?

Comment: _POST_ can be pretty much exactly the same as _GET_ in terms of how the data looks, the difference is where the data is, i.e. you `send` the `"csv_data=" +encodeURIComponent(csv)` and read it in _PHP_ with `$_POST["csv_data"]` or `$_REQUEST["csv_data"]`. If your code works with small data and _GET_ - the issue being only long URIs, and so you switched where you're sending the data to _POST_ in your _JavaScript_, remember to mirror this change in your _PHP_ if it's not already ready for it

Comment: it would probably be easiest just to change the form action to the php page you want to process it, and send everything via post

Comment: @Tobias : not possible simply. Formatting is done in JS side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over-complicating this just a bit.  There is no need for all of the JS redirect stuff, you can just point your forms action attribute to your csv_export php code and use POST to send your data.

if needed, you can modify the max size of a post request by editing the post_max_size option in your php.ini.  heres what mine looks like:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
```

as for writing to a temporary file, php has built in  I/O streams to handle that.   for your purposes you'll probably want to use php://memory or php://temp (more info on those here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

so you can do something like this:

SAMPLE HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- include jquery because you say you are using it -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
//just a dummy function to represent your js to extract csv data from a table
function extract_table_data(){
    var csv = "field1,field2,field3\n\
value1,value2,value3\n\
value4,value5,value5";
    return csv;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    //export link click handler
    $('#export_link').click(function() {
        $('#csv_data').val(extract_table_data());
        $('#theform').submit();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id='export_link'>Export CSV</a>
<form id='theform' method='post' action='dropcsv.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='csv_data' id='csv_data'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

dropcsv.php

```
//filename for our csv attachment
$export_filename = 'thefile.csv';
//grab csv data
$csv_data = $_POST['csv_data'];
//open file in memory
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); //use php://temp if you want a tmp file instead
//load up csv file
fwrite($f, $csv_data);
// go back to the beginning of the file
fseek($f, 0);
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$export_filename.'"');
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
```

of course don't forget to add your error checking and sanitize the input.

Comment: Many thank's ! It does the trick. Looking forward I've find a jquery plugin (jquery.redirect available http://www.avramovic.info/razno/jquery/redirect/) which does exactly what you propose.

Comment: Another thank for your valuable response about using temporay file in Php.